# If string exceeds character length move to next line whilst keeping words intact

Tags: c#, txt

I'm writing to a txt file using filename.writeline("Content"). I want to move to the next line if its over 20 characters but keep the words intact. (Only applies to the comment/narrative section)

Currently it looks like this -

```
$$REMIT:Our Ref     Your Ref    DOA         Reg No.     Amount      Comments    
$$REMIT:--------------------------------------------------------------------
$$REMIT:REFERENCE               01/01/1900  AAAAAAA     50.0000     Full & Final Settlem
$$REMIT:                                                            ent
```

It should look like this -

```
$$REMIT:Our Ref     Your Ref    DOA         Reg No.     Amount      Comments    
$$REMIT:--------------------------------------------------------------------
$$REMIT:REFERENCE              01/01/1900  AAAAAAA     50.0000     Full & Final
$$REMIT:                                                           Settlement
```

Currently Using this -

```
string formatDate = Convert.ToDateTime(PaymentsOutput.IncidentDate_date).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy").TrimEnd();

// Column Names
outputFile.WriteLine("$$REMIT:" + "Our Ref".PadRight(12) + "Your Ref".PadRight(12) + "DOA".PadRight(12) + "Reg No.".PadRight(12) + "Amount".PadRight(12) + "Comments".PadRight(12));

// Line Separator
outputFile.WriteLine("$$REMIT:".PadRight(76,'-'));

// Column Content
outputFile.Write("$$REMIT:" + PaymentsOutput.ClaimRef_char.PadRight(12) + PaymentsOutput.YourRef_char.PadRight(12) +
formatDate.PadRight(12) + PaymentsOutput.RegNo_char.PadRight(12) +
PaymentsOutput.PaymentAmount_money.ToString().PadRight(12));

int countNarative = PaymentsOutput.Narative_char.Length;
if (countNarative > 20)
{
    do
    {
        outputFile.WriteLine(PaymentsOutput.Narative_char.Substring(0, 20));
        countNarative = countNarative - 20;
        outputFile.WriteLine("$$REMIT:".PadRight(68) + PaymentsOutput.Narative_char.Substring(20));
    } while (countNarative > 20);
}
else
{
    outputFile.WriteLine(PaymentsOutput.Narative_char);
}
```

Note - I'm matching the format to some existing files because its picked up by another process, I    can't change the inherently bad formatting.

Comment: "I want X" is not a good way to phrase your question.  (Hint: One of your sentences should end with a question mark.)  Instead, explain the problem you encountered.  Share with us a minimal way of reproducing the issue, and then describe your expected results vs your actual results.  Be sure to talk about why you're convinced your approach should be giving the expected results and why you're surprised that it did something unexpected.

Comment: If I understood your problem, you need a way to split a string in chunks of max 20 chars. You could use the `LastIndexOf` method of the string to get the latest space before the desired position. E.g. `myString.LastIndexOf(' ', 20)` gives you the position of where to split the string. Obviously if there is a word  with a lenght greater than 20 chars you must truncate the word. I suggest to split code to calculate rows for comments string in a specific method so you can test it indipendently

Comment: No, 20 is right since `startIndex` parameter is the index in the char array, and the index in an array start from zero. See this example [on .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/g9PpEB)

Comment: You need more than just a word preserving newline if we need to take your example into account. There are columns.

Comment: Thanks @RobertoFerraris! I managed to complete it using Indexing.

Answer (score 0):

Completed by indexing and cycling through the string

```
outputFile.Write("$$REMIT:" + PaymentsOutput.ClaimRef_char.PadRight(12) + PaymentsOutput.YourRef_char.PadRight(12) + formatDate.PadRight(12) + PaymentsOutput.RegNo_char.PadRight(12) + PaymentsOutput.PaymentAmount_money.ToString().PadRight(12));

// - Narative needs to be wrapped 
// Get string length
int NarativeLength = PaymentsOutput.Narative_char.Length;
// Wrap if over 20 characters
if (NarativeLength > 20)
{
    // Prints first line without 
    int startNarative = PaymentsOutput.Narative_char.LastIndexOf(' ', 20);
    outputFile.WriteLine(PaymentsOutput.Narative_char.Substring(0, startNarative));

    // 20 max line length
    int charCount = 20;

    do
    {
        // Get the new starting point for the next line
        startNarative = PaymentsOutput.Narative_char.LastIndexOf(' ', charCount);
        charCount = charCount + 20;
        int endNarative = 0;

        // Set end point to whatever the total length is if we hit 80. If we use greater than the max length in substring itll break
        if (charCount != 80) 
        {
            endNarative = PaymentsOutput.Narative_char.LastIndexOf(' ', charCount);
        }
        else
        {
            endNarative = PaymentsOutput.Narative_char.Length;
        }

        // Write text between start and end points
        outputFile.WriteLine("$$REMIT:".PadRight(68) + PaymentsOutput.Narative_char.Substring(startNarative, endNarative - indNarative));


        NarativeLength = PaymentsOutput.Narative_char.Length - endNarative;

    } while (NarativeLength > 1);
}
// If under 20 characters we can just append it onto the line like normal
else
{
    outputFile.WriteLine(PaymentsOutput.Narative_char);
''''
```

Comment: You should have way of it coping if there are no spaces in the first 20 characters - maybe the spaces got missed out, or someone used a different whitespace character. (Also, you should put that 20 into a variable with a sensible name so that it is easy to change.)

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to split text by length:

```
IEnumerable<string> SplitToLines(string stringToSplit, int maximumLineLength)
{
    var words = stringToSplit.Split(' ');
    var line = words.First();
    foreach (var word in words.Skip(1))
    {
        var test = $"{line} {word}";
        if (test.Length > maximumLineLength)
        {
            yield return line;
            line = word;
        }
        else
        {
            line = test;
        }
    }
    yield return line;
}
```

Running `SplitToLines("Full & Final Settlement", 20)` produces:

[image: result]